# Struts 2 Action error

Tags: java, struts2, struts-action

I have a problem with struts 2 action error while forwarding from one action to another action .The problem lies as there is a interceptor in between and we are doing a redirect action

Can I some how copy the action error from old action to current action
or save the action error in the session?

It will highly appreciable if some one gives a working peice of code

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to redirect to show your error?

Answer (score 0):

Your result type is currently "redirect" or "redirectAction" these reset the value stack use "chain". Although you should generally look for a solution that does not use any of the aforementioned result types...

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem for showing successfully saved message. Here's what I got while googling the solution. http://glindholm.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/preserving-messages-across-a-redirect-in-struts-2/
Hope it helps you.